# No such customer: 'cus_OIR5UsvZncTECx'; a similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe with the firebase extension and have recently swtiched from test mode to live mode on Stripe. I've recreated the products and modified the webhook and API keys on on my firebase extension. However, when I try to create a checkout session, the session returns this error:

> No such customer: 'cus_OIR5UsvZncTECx. A similar object exists in test mode, but a live mode key was used to make this request.

```
const checkoutSessionRef = doc(sessionRef, checkoutSessionId);
  onSnapshot(checkoutSessionRef, async (snap) => {
    console.log(snap.data())
    const { sessionId } = snap.data();
    console.log(snap.data().sessionId)
    console.log(sessionId)
    if (snap.exists()) {
      const stripe = await getStripe();
      stripe.redirectToCheckout( {sessionId});
    }
  });
```

My data that I was testing out stripe payments on was the same as my live data, so I know that there is some issue with a customer duplicate. However, I'm wondering if there's a way around this where I can automatically switch my customer data and live data.

Comment: The error states the issue - you're using a Test mode customer to try and create a transaction in Live mode. You need to create a brand new customer in Live mode, then try the transaction again against that customer Id

Comment: `I'm wondering if there's a way around this where I can automatically switch my customer data and live data`. No - you need to manually re-create them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would need to write a script that deletes all my users and then manually creates them again. Wouldn't this get complicated if I used firebase OAuth and sign-in-with-google? I'm not sure how I can recreate without harming the customer experience as I already have a few users for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this due to attempting to use a customer ID that was created in test mode while you're now using live mode. Customer IDs (and other object IDs) are separate between test and live mode, so you cannot use a test customer ID in live mode (same for all other Stripe objects).

You need to create new customer in your live mode. You can use [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-metadata) to link both test and live mode object or track that in your firestore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I looked up how to use metadata but I don't understand the logic to be able to use this for my problem? On my prod env, I was using test mode for stripe and I obtained users using test mode. Now I want to switch to live mode but I don't want to delete my users as that will require them to login again which I'm not sure if they'll all remember to. How do I switch old users that were created to test mode to live mode using the metadata tag?

Comment: The idea is to create new Stripe Customer Object in your live mode, and in the metadata of each object you store the customerId of the test mode Customer Object, so that you keep track of your objects between live and test mode.